# EnableDelayedExpansion and still set global environment variables

Tags: batch-file

```
setlocal
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (%env_cells%) do (
    call :env_setter env_setter_%%a
)
goto:EOF

:env_setter
rem doesn't do anything
endlocal
call %%1
goto:eof
```

The problem is the above disables the setting of global variables in all calls spawned by :env_call. Is there a way to resolve this?

Perhaps this is a more detailed explanation:

env_setter is a call to a batch file that itself contains `set` calls with the intention to set environment variables on this calling context. Because `setlocal` is enabled during the call to !env_cell! and the endlocal in :env_cell does not appear to disable endlocal, said set calls do not change this context as intended.

In this particular example, one can use %%a but I wish to understand this functionality in general.

Is there a manual way to access a variable value reflectively in a if/for block?

Comment: Do you want to '_move_' variables from a '_delayed expansion_' environment back to the 'start' environment?

Comment: Yup, I would like to be able to have set calls in the child process to effect the calling environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to use an endlocal in a function to leave a setlocal which is set outside the function.

But when a syntax error occours all setlocal instances are still alive and can't be removed with endlocal, so this can set global variables.

```
setlocal
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (%env_cells%) do (
    call :env_setter env_setter_%%a
)
goto:EOF

:env_setter
set myNewGlobal=1
call :haltAndStore
goto:eof

:haltAndStore
()
```

Comment: Is there a way to facilitate the functionality? The updated specified is interesting, but it is not relevant because it terminates the script.

Comment: I don't know a way to survive the halt (I believe there isn't any possiblity). But the way of foxidrive could be a solution

Comment: I was refering to the possibility of accessing variables in the block in some other way reflectively. I have to go right now but I'm thinking you can write to disk or memory manually if that is possible.

Answer (score 6):

#### Throw your variables over the wall!

```
@echo off &setlocal
echo(

echo this obviously doesn't work
set "Counter="
for /l %%a in (1 1 5) do (
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    set "Counter=!Counter!1"
    set "Variable=!Variable!!Counter!"
    echo !Counter!:!Variable!
    endlocal
)
echo Counter's value in the calling environment : %Counter%
echo Variable's value in the calling environment: %Variable%
echo(
    
echo throw your variables over the wall!
set "Counter="
for /l %%a in (1 1 5) do (
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    set "Counter=!Counter!1"
    set "Variable=!Variable!!Counter!"
    echo !Counter!:!Variable!
    for /f %%a in ('set Counter^&set Variable') do (if "!"=="" endlocal)&set "%%a"
)
echo Counter's value in the calling environment : %Counter%
echo Variable's value in the calling environment: %Variable%
```

Comment: @MetaChrome       I changed from 'numeric' to 'string' variables. The result is more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I used @jeb answer to implement assigning IP addresses to environment variables. Possibly my worst hack ever.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set _count=1
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`ipconfig ^| findstr /i "ipv4"`) do (
    for /f delims^=^:^ tokens^=2 %%b in ('echo %%a') do (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%c IN ('echo %%b') do (set IP!_count!=%%c & echo IP!_count!=%%c & set /a _count+= 1)
    )
)
set _count=
call :haltAndStore 2> nul

:haltAndStore
()
```